# easy to refactor a static method call from an abstract class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

I have lots of refences to this

```
MyAbstractClass.myStatic()
```

And I want to change them to non static method of an normal class, that is

```
myOtherClass.myMethod()
```

is there an easy way to do this using intellij ?

Comment: find and replace ????

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ well yeah I guess, won;t do the import for me though

Comment: No, there's no easy way, because the instance `myOtherClass` needs to come from somewhere, unlike the class name of `MyAbstractClass`, which you can obtain "from the thin air".

Comment: I don't see any imports which would have to be added.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik myOtherClass would need to be imported, and injected/autowired

Comment: `myOtherClass` is a variable, of type `MyAbstractClass` (or at least assignment-compatible with that class). If you are talking about another, unrelated class, you can first move the static method to the new class, which will fix the imports. Then you are left with the major problem of resolving an actual instance.

Answer (score 1):

If `MyOtherClass` has a no-parameter constructor and you're OK calling it on a new instance every time, you could change the original method to

public void myStatic() {
    new MyAbstractClass().myStatic();
}

and then inline the method.  Similarly, if `MyAbstractClass` could hold a public static instance of `MyOtherClass` then the original method could be inlined.